# Curl with sudo returns connection refused, but plain curl runs fine

Tags: linux, curl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The following runs fine

```
curl https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/config_file.list?os=Ubuntu\&dist=xenial\&source=script
```

But if I run it with `sudo` it returns an error:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to packagecloud.io port 443: Connection refused`

Why?

Note: I'm behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: I'd run it with "-v" and compare "good" and "bad" outputs. It could be local firewall rules that look at uid of the process associated with the socket, but my bet is on local proxy settings being different between these users.

Comment: Try `sudo -E curl...` to preserve the `https_proxy` environment variable or whitelist it in the sudoers file.

Comment: @cfillion your suggestion works. Can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

curl reads the `<url scheme>_proxy` (in this case, `https_proxy`) or `all_proxy` environment variables to set the default proxy server to use (as documented [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html#Environment)). However, by default, sudo executes commands in a minimal environment (`env_reset` setting).

This safety feature can be temporarily disabled, so that existing environment variables are preserved, using the `-E` (`--preserve-env`) command line option. Individual environment variables to whitelist can be specified as a comma-separated list:

```
sudo --preserve-env=https_proxy curl ...
```

This can be made permanent using the `env_keep` setting in the [sudoers](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.27/sudoers.man.html#Command_environment) file. For example, to preserve all environment variables ending with `_proxy` for all users:

```
Defaults env_keep += "*_proxy"
```